# Deleting a row is not cascading down to delete related data

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .NetCore 3 Entity Framework project.

I am testing an API endpoint that deletes an entry in the PlantList table.

When that entry is deleted, I also want it to delete the row in another table called PlantSequence that corresponds to the same plantID that is being deleted in PlantList.

So I added this to the end of the modeBuilder in my context class:

```
entity.HasOne(p => p.PlantSequence)
      .WithOne(i => i.Plant)
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

But when I use Postman to test, and I delete an entry in PlantList, the row in PlantSequence is still there in the database.

What could I be doing wrong?

Here is the whole PlantList entry in my context class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PlantList>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.PlantId)
                    .HasName("PK_PlantList");

                entity.ToTable("plantList");

                entity.Property(e => e.PlantId)
                    .HasColumnName("plantID")
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.PlantText).HasColumnName("plantText");

                entity.HasOne(p => p.PlantSequence)
                .WithOne(i => i.Plant)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            });
```

And here is the whole entry for PlantSequence:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<PlantSequence>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.PlantId);

            entity.ToTable("PlantSequence");

            entity.Property(e => e.PlantId)
                .HasColumnName("PlantId");

            entity.Property(e => e.PlantQi)
                .HasColumnName("PlantQi");

            entity.Property(e => e.PlantRNAi)
                .HasColumnName("PlantRNAi");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Plant)
                  .WithMany()
                  .HasForeignKey(d => d.PlantId);
        });
```

Here is my PlantList class:

```
public partial class PlantList
{

    public string PlantId{ get; set; }
    public string PlantText{ get; set; }

    public  PlantSequence PlantSequence{ get; set; }
}
```

And here is my PlantSequence class:

```
public partial class PlantSequence 
{
    public Guid PlantSequenceId { get; set; }
    public string PlantId{ get; set; }
    public int PlantQi { get; set; }
    public int PlantRNAi { get; set; }

    public virtual PlantList Plant { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You have `HasOne` + `WithOne` from one side, then `HasOne` + `WithMany` from the other side. These are two relationships. It's unclear how many and what type of relationships are you trying to create, and which one should cascade delete and in which direction. If looking only at navigation properties, it looks like singe one-to-one relationship, nut your fluent configuration is confusing. Please edit the question and provide that info.